# Atualizar pagina depois de enviar o formulario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Bom galera pode parecer algo simples , mais eu nao estou conseguindo , eu tenho uma pagina de insert que funciona perfeitamente , apos eu fazer o insert eu uso o

```
<script>
history.go(-2) 
</script>
```

para volta duas paginas atras e nessa pagina lista os meus itens da tabela , mas quando ele volta parece que a pagina nao atualiza entao nao aparece meu novo item da tabela , para ele aparecer eu preciso atualizar a pagina , teria como apos eu enviar o formulario atualizar dps volta as paginas ?

Meu codigo inteiro :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link  type="text/javascript" href="jquery.js">
<link type="text/javascript" href="post.js">
<link  type="text/javascript" href="jquery-form.js">
<body >
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <?php
        ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');



        if(isset($_POST['send'])){
            $produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
            $id_venda = $_POST['id_venda'];


            include ('banco.php');

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedido(id, produtos, id_venda )
            values(
                NULL,
                '{$produtos}',
                '{$id_venda}'
                              )
            ");

            echo  '<script>history.go(-2) </script>';
        }

        ?>
        <legend style="color: #ffffff" class="btn btn-inverse">Cadastro </legend>

        <?php
        ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');

        mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

        mysql_select_db('mecanica');

        $query='Select * from produtos';

        ?>


        <label for="produtos" style="color: #000"><strong>Produto : </strong></label>
        <select name="produtos" style="width: 400px">
            <?php
            //execução da query
            $resultado=mysql_query($query);


            while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
            {

                echo '<option  value="' . $linha['id_produto'] . '">' . $linha['produtos'] . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </select><br><br>

        <?php   $id_ven  = $_GET["id_venda"];    ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function mostra() {
                if (document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display == 'block'){
                    document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'none';
                }else {document.getElementById('ocultar').style.display = 'block'}
            }

        </script>


        <div id="ocultar" style="visibility: hidden" >

    <?php
        ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');

        mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

        mysql_select_db('mecanica');

        $query='Select * from pedido';
        ?>


        <label for="id_venda" style="color: #000"><strong>ID VENDA : </strong></label>
        <select name="id_venda" style="width: 75px">
            <?php
           $resultado=mysql_query($query);
            while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
            {

            }
            echo '<option >' . $_GET['id_venda'] . '</option>';

            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </select><br><br>


        </div>


        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Enviar" name="send">
        <a href="listadevendas.php" class="btn btn-inverse">Cancelar</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar `location.href = "pagina"` para redirecionar a pagina escolhida?

Comment: Ja sim , mas a minha pagina q eu volto e por id , ai no location.href nao pegava i ID da pagina

Comment: Bom, vc poderia usar `location.href = "pagina.php?id=111"` passando o ID por GET, se vc tiver ele na sua página atual... Se não faça ele ser recebido nessa pagina, senão não conheço outra forma...

Comment: Tentei assim , mas nao volta no mesmo id ;/

Comment: history.go não é solução para isso, use um `header( 'location: /pagina/correta' );` seguido de um `exit();` (mas **antes de exibir dados na tela**). E evite chamar JavaScript de PHP. Praticamente em todos os lugares em que você encontrar isso, é coisa de quem não sabe o que está fazendo (pode ter alguma exceção, mas até agora não vi nenhuma). Pra você ter uma idéia, tem gente que chega no ponto de chamar `alert` de PHP em vez de mostrar a mensagem na página.

Comment: Qual é a variavel que guarda o Id que vc precisa nessa página?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

após o INSERT do dados use a função header do PHP.

header('location:url_da_pagina'), para ser redirecionado para a página.

Comment: Lembrando que ele tem que refatorar o código, pois o location só vai funcionar se ele nao tiver posto nada no HTML ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Bom eu conseguir resolver assim:

```
header("location:cabecalho.php?&id={$id} ");
```